# ItemsControl TextBox Name is not Working in .cs File

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My WPF Application  code generates panels on `function call` defined in .cs file. There is `ItemControl` used in code to generates these `Panels` . I want to Name Textbox defined in this `ItemControl` and to use this in code. I named it as `textEdit1` and used it in code but code generated error that `textEdit1` doesn't exist. Can anyone solve my problem? Here Code is:

**XAML File:**

```
<dxlc:ScrollBox>
    <ItemsControl Name="lstPanels">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="vertical">
                    <Grid>
                        <dxe:TextEdit Height="165" Text="{Binding Text,
                                    Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="textEdit1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</dxlc:ScrollBox>
```

**.CS FILE**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    string valuu;
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        addPanel("Header1");
        addPanel("Header2");
        addPanel("Header3");
        lstPanels.ItemsSource = panels;

    }
    public ObservableCollection<MyPanel> panels = new ObservableCollection<MyPanel>();
    public void addPanel(string buttonId)
    {
        MyPanel p = new MyPanel { Id = buttonId};
        panels.Add(p); 
        functionb(p);
    }
    public void functionb(MyPanel obj)
    {        
        valuu = obj.Text;            
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var f in panels.ToList())
        {
            MessageBox.Show( f.Id + "   ***   "  + f.Text);
        }
    }
}

public class MyPanel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id;
    private string _text;

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _text)
            {
                _text = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(  String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are using some 3rd party libraries for your TextBox and ScrollBox. If you provide me with the names of the libraries, I could have a look at them as the functionality might be different from what WPF has out-of-the-box.
As for now you have 3 options (I am giving examples for standard TextBox and ItemsControl):

**I) You do not have to access the textbox at all.**
An easy way around it is described here: [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492814/increasing-or-decreasing-control-fontsize-on-runtime-according-to-sliderwpf-com)

**II) Handling events and references to TextBoxes in the code behind**

1. Add a `Loaded` event to your TextBox:

   ```
   <TextBox x:Name="txtText" Width="300" Height="100" Loaded="txtText_Loaded" />
   ```
2. Add a field to your MyPanel class to hold a reference to a TextBox:

   ```
   public class MyPanel
   {
       public string Text { get; set; }
       public TextBox TextBox { get; set; }
       /* the rest ... */
   }
   ```
3. Add a counter to your window, next to a list with panels:

   ```
   protected ObservableCollection<MyPanel> panels = new ObservableCollection<MyPanel>();
   private int counter = 0;
   ```
4. Handle the Load event of the TextBox:

   ```
   private void txtText_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       panels[counter].TextBox = (TextBox)sender;
       counter++;
   }
   ```
5. If you want to access a particular TextBox, do it this way:

   ```
   MessageBox.Show(panels[i].TextBox.Text);
   ```

**III) Add additional bindings for FontSize:**

1. Add a FontSize property to your MyPanel class:

   ```
   private double _fontSize = 10;
   public double FontSize
   {
       get { return _fontSize; }
       set
       {
           if (value != _fontSize)
           {
               _fontSize = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Bind just added property to the TextBox in your ItemsControl:

   ```
   <TextBox x:Name="txtText" Width="300" Height="100" Text="{Binding Text;, Mode=TwoWay}"
            FontSize="{Binding FontSize, Mode=OneWay}" />
   ```
3. Add a slider to the template and bind it to the same property:

   ```
   <Slider Minimum="10" Maximum="30" Value="{Binding FontSize, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   ```

This way if you change the value on a slider, it will change the value in your MyPanel object bound to the panel. This in turn will change the font size of the textbox.

My whole code I tested it on looks like that:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="lstItems" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtText" Width="300" Height="100" Text="{Binding Text;, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="{Binding FontSize, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <Slider Minimum="10" Maximum="30" Value="{Binding FontSize, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    protected ObservableCollection<MyPanel> texts = new ObservableCollection<MyPanel>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        texts.Add(new MyPanel() { Text = "Test 1" });
        texts.Add(new MyPanel() { Text = "Test 2" });

        lstItems.ItemsSource = texts;
    }
}

public class MyPanel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id;
    private string _text;
    private double _fontSize = 10;

    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _text)
            {
                _text = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public double FontSize
    {
        get { return _fontSize; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _fontSize)
            {
                _fontSize = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I personally would go with the last solution.
But again, let me know what libraries you are using, and I will have look at them when I have some time. Good luck.

Comment: Thank's for response! Daniel i am using Devexpress TextEdit. it's all properties are similar to TextBox by WPF! ok have you read my this comment `ok let me explain you: There are Panels in ItemControl, each with unique id but same headers. Now in each Panel there is a TextBox and a slider. Selected slider will increase font size of text within it's Panel. How to get this selected Slider of panel to apply changes to textbox.Text, as there are many panels? `  I need all this to play with textbox.Text. To increase it's font size, alignment, etc by using slider and buttons.

Comment: Well I guess your best bet will be using what I have described as your 3rd option.

Comment: I used Tag to get Selected Slider now problem is how to get textbox.Text of that selected slider panel?

Comment: As I said in my post: don't try to access the TextBox or Slider from the template in the code behind. Much neater is to bind a slider to a variable in your MyPanel, so that the slider changes the variable value, and then bind OneWay the variable to TextBox FontSize property. This way changes on the slider will change the font size of the TextBox. It is described in my post as point **III)**

Comment: Daniel can i use FontSize Code for alignment of text?

Comment: You could probably have radio button or dropdown with alignments bound to the MyPanel in a similar way, and then your variable bound again to appropriate property of a textbox. Play with it :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Daniel for your time. Let me try all this and will surely mark this as solution and please one last query that if i want to move panels up or down. Example: There are three Panels `PanelA, PanelB, PanelC` now now there is button with each panel to move it up. Now i selected PanleB. i click on that button and PanelB will move up now they should be like `PanelB, PanelA, PanelC`! // Or should i post this as another question on stack overflow?

Comment: post it as another question as it is completly unrelated query :)

Comment: Here Question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185273/how-to-change-panels-position-in-wpf-itemcomtrols

Comment: Daniel i am waiting for reply `In Alignment how to change values from left to right? ` and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185273/how-to-change-panels-position-in-wpf-itemcomtrols`

Comment: Daniel can you answer may question2 too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188661/how-to-set-alignment-of-a-textbox-text-in-wpf-via-inotify-property   ??

Answer (score 2):

`textEdit1` is part of a template that will be instantiated multiple times, so there will be multiple instances of `textEdit1`. It wouldn't make sense to generate a field for `textEdit1` in the class, because it could only refer to one instance the `TextEdit` control...

Comment: Thank's for reply! is there any alternative?

Comment: @user2835256, an alternative to do what? You didn't say what you were trying to achieve...

Comment: i want to name this textedit to apply changes to text write by user in it.

Comment: OK, but *which* TextEdit, since there will be several of them? You can subscribe to events of the control in XAML, and access the control through the `sender` argument

Comment: ok let me explain you:  There are Panels in ItemControl, each with unique id but same headers. Now in each Panel there is a TextBox and a slider. Selected slider will increase font size of text within it's Panel. How to get this selected Slider of panel to apply changes to textbox.Text, as there are many panels?