# How to set Alignment of a textbox.Text in wpf via INotify-Property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My WPF Application code generates panels on function call defined in .cs file. There is ItemControl used in code to generates these Panels . I want to to change text Alignment of text of Textbox defined in selected panel via it's button. Query: I clicked button and alignment of select panel TextBox change from left to rightand from right to left, Now implementation of Alignment sets  if select slider to move. Here code is:

**XAML FILE**

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="lstItemsClassM">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Content="{Binding Alignment, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Click="Button_Click"
                Tag="{Binding PKId}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtText"
                 Width="300"
                 Height="100"
                 Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 FontSize="{Binding FontSize, Mode=OneWay}"
                 TextAlignment="{Binding Alignment, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Slider Minimum="10"
                Maximum="30"
                Value="{Binding FontSize, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

**.CS FILE**

```
 protected ObservableCollection<ClassM> texts = new ObservableCollection<ClassM>();
    int dv;
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dv=1;
        texts.Add(new ClassM() { PKId=dv, Text = "Test 1" });
        dv=2;
        texts.Add(new ClassM() { PKId=dv, Text = "Test 2" });

        lstItemsClassM.ItemsSource = texts;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myValue = ((Button)sender).Tag;
           foreach (var f in texts.ToList())
            {
                if (f.PKId.ToString() == myValue.ToString())
                {
                    f._alignment = "Right";
                    MessageBox.Show(f._alignment);
                }
            }
    }    
}


public class ClassM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id;
    private int _pkid;
    private string _text;
    private double _fontSize = 10;
    public string _alignment="Left";

    public int PKId
    {
        get { return _pkid; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _pkid)
            {
                _pkid = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _text)
            {
                _text = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public double FontSize
    {
        get { return _fontSize; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _fontSize)
            {
                _fontSize = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public string Alignment
    {
        get { return _alignment; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _alignment)
            {
                _alignment = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Alignment means Textbox.Text Alignment `left to right` or `right to left`**

Comment: Then you will need a property Alignment of type [FrameworkElement.FlowDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.flowdirection.aspx) not string and have to bind to TextBox.FlowDirection.

Comment: @LPL That would be `System.Windows.FlowDirection` and yes, WPF is able to convert from `string` to any enum type implicitly in the DataBinding pipeline, so you don't really need to tie your VM to `System.Windows` in order to do this

Comment: @HighCore i want that as i click on button it's content change from left to right or right to to left and these changes should apply on flowdirection of textbox.text

Comment: @HighCore Yes, I meant [System.Windows.FlowDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.flowdirection.aspx). And does that mean you can bind `TextBox.FlowDirection` to a string as long as string content is *LeftToRight* or *RightToLeft* and it will work?

Comment: yes @LPL ... i want to change flowdireciton on button click

Comment: @HighCore  i want to change flowdireciton on button click ?

Comment: @user2835256 Try it out: Bind Alignment to `TextBox.FlowDirection` and replace `f._alignment = "Right";` with `f.Alignment = "RightToLeft";`. Be aware: `f.Alignment` to call PropertyChange, not `f._alignment`.

Comment: @LPL No i think my question is not clear to you. see! there i have button with content `Right` ok and i have slider to change text font size. Now i want to change text alignment on button click. ok?? Now Problem is `As i click on button it changes alignment but doesn't implement on text and implements only if  i move slider` -- Is this clear to you now? :)

Answer (score -2):

The best solution is use RichTextBox to align your text. If you wanna i could sugest one implementation to read a literal string and format.